# my output goes into non alphabetic values python 3.4 caesar cipher

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

```
user_m = input('enter message:')
user_k = int(input('enter offset key:'))

message = ''

for a in user_m:
    r = ord(a)
    r += user_k
    message += chr(r)
print (message)
```

this code encrypts a message by adding the offset key to the message. It works fine but the problem is that the output is sometimes going into non-alphabetical values and sometimes not accurate e.g

```
enter message:zyxabc
enter offset key:24
yz{
```

here is an example of when it works

```
enter message:hello
enter offset key:5
mjqqt
```

how do i keep all the characters alphabetical?

Comment: Well what is the next letter in the alphabet after 'z'?

Comment: @StefanPochmann: That problem was [solved in Geisel, 1955](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Beyond_Zebra!).

Comment: You may want to look at the `%` operator to solve this. Or, if that doesn't immediately make sense to you, you probably want an `if` statement that compares `r` with `ord('z')`, and does something appropriate if so.

Comment: While we're at it: you may want to consider what to do if the input contains things that aren't lowercase English letters. What do you want to do for uppercase letters? Spaces and punctuation? Non-English letters like å? Whatever it is, just unconditionally adding 24 to the `ord` is probably not the answer.

Comment: The next ordinal after `z` (122) is `{` (123). As @abarnert said, unconditionally adding an amount to the ordinals will lead to non-alpha characters.

Comment: One last thing: I don't _think_ this will be any easier to understand, but just in case: take a look at how Python's own [`rot_13`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/encodings/rot_13.py) codec solves this problem. Someone precomputed the dict mapping each letter to its rotated letter, and then the codec just looks up each character in the dict. (You don't need a whole codec for this, just `str.translate`, or even manually calling `message += mapping.get(c, c)` on each `c`.)

Comment: Try using ``string.ascii_lowercase`` instead of ``ord()`` and ``chr()``.

Comment: If only alpha characters are expected, `ord` will work fine. @pzp

Comment: @Zach Gates Yes, it would work fine. I'm just offering an alternate solution.

Comment: @pzp: I think calling `find` or `index` on `ascii_lowercase`, then dealing with the -1 or exception, etc. is going to be less readable and easier to get wrong than just comparing to `'a'` and `'z'` and calling `ord` (as well as being a bit less efficient, not that it matters in this use case). Also, it prevents you from discovering the cleverer `%`-based solution.

Comment: @pzp: Unless you're proposing a `rotate string` function that could be used to build a mapping from `ascii_lowercase` to `rotate_string(ascii_lowercase, user_k)` and then just, e.g., pass that to `user_m.translate`, which is another clever solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the first solution that @abarnet suggested in the comments:

```
def encrypt(message, shift):
    new = ''
    for i in (ord(x) for x in message): #gets the ascii value of each letter in message
        if 64 < i < 91: #uppercase
            new += chr(65 + (i+shift-65)%26)
        elif 96 < i < 123: #lowercase
            new += chr(97 + (i+shift-97)%26)
    return new

def decrypt(message, shift):
    return encrypt(message, 26-shift)
```